# My char pointer returns weird string

Tags: c, arrays, string, char

As trying to concatenate two strings (char arrays), the code below returns the correct result via `return` but not the expected result through the arguments passed by reference (namely, `char *dst` in the `StrAdd` function).

Concerning the "after" results; `printf` prints the correct concatenated string for st. But the variable "s1" is supposed to contain the concatenated string as well. However, s1 prints something weird.

Can someone figure out what's wrong with it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *StrAdd (char *dst, const char *src) {
/*  add source string "src" at the end of destination string "dst"
    i.e. concatenate
*/
    size_t lenDst = strlen (dst);
    size_t lenSrc = strlen (src);
    size_t lenTot = lenDst + lenSrc + 1;
    char *sTmp = (char *) malloc (lenTot);
    memcpy (&sTmp [0], &dst [0], lenDst);
    memcpy (&sTmp [lenDst], &src [0], lenSrc);
    sTmp [lenTot - 1] = '\0';
    free (dst);
    dst = (char *) malloc (lenTot);
    memcpy (&dst [0], &sTmp [0], lenTot);
    free (sTmp);
    return (dst);
}

int main () {
    char *s1 = strdup ("Xxxxx");
    char *s2 = strdup ("Yyyyy");
    char *st = strdup ("Qqqqq");

    printf ("s1 before: \"%s\"\n", s1);
    printf ("s2 before: \"%s\"\n", s2);
    printf ("st before: \"%s\"\n", st);
    printf ("\n");

    st = StrAdd (s1, s2);

    printf ("s1 after : \"%s\"\n", s1); // weird???
    printf ("s2 after : \"%s\"\n", s2); // ok
    printf ("st after : \"%s\"\n", st); // ok
    printf ("\n");

    return (0);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to create and return a new string, just return the `sTmp` you alloced and do not free the `dst`.

```
char *StrAdd (const char *dst, const char *src) {
    size_t lenDst = strlen (dst);
    size_t lenSrc = strlen (src);
    size_t lenTot = lenDst + lenSrc + 1;
    char *sTmp = (char *) malloc (lenTot);
    memcpy (&sTmp [0], &dst [0], lenDst);
    memcpy (&sTmp [lenDst], &src [0], lenSrc + 1); //+1 copies the existing nil char from src
    return sTmp;
}
```

On the other hand if you do want the destination pointer passed in to be updated, you will need to pass it by reference, a pointer to a pointer:

```
char *StrAdd (char** dstPtr, const char *src) {
    char* dst = *dstPtr;
    size_t lenDst = strlen (dst);
    size_t lenSrc = strlen (src);
    size_t lenTot = lenDst + lenSrc + 1;
    char *sTmp = (char *) realloc (dst, lenTot); //realloc will also copy the old data for us
    strcat(sTmp, src); //same as the second memcpy
    *dstPtr = sTmp; //update dest pointer
    return sTmp;
}
```

But you will need to call it like this:

```
st = StrAdd (&s1, s2);
```

After this, `s1` and `st` point to the same string, try this to see that:

```
printf ("Addresses after: %p %p\n", (void*)s1, (void*)st);
```

Comment: Maybe @2501's explanation is correct but your solutions seems better. This way, I think, the pointer to `*s1` will not get lost.

Comment: I've added a way of updating `s1`. Just make sure you have no other references to that string as it gets freed.

Comment: That is it **could** get freed by the realloc. realloc may not change the pointer.

Comment: Still, your first code (returning the newly defined `char *`, ie. `sTmp`) seems better. This way, if I want to use the old `s1` after the function, I would use `sNew = StrAdd (s1, s2);` and if I allow the old `s1` to be changed, I would use `s1 = StrAdd (s1, s2);`

Comment: Problem with this: `s1 = StrAdd (s1, s2);` Is that nothing frees the old `s1` and you will get a memory leak. `char *newS1 = StrAdd (s1, s2); free(s1); s1 = newS1;` would be the way to do that.

Answer (score 8):

You passed `s1` to the function and then called free on it. After you do that the pointer is no longer valid, and you cannot use it. If you do, like you did in printf(), you get undefined behavour.

Comment: Ok, I free the dst in the function once, but then allocate another memory space for that variable. Doesn't that second allocation return back the pointer via the `*dst` argument in the header? As printed in the main, it returns the correct pointer via `return (dst)`; why not via `*dst` in the header?

Comment: @merkez3110 No, you're freeing `s1` and assigning the newly allocated memory to `st`. Please see a proper implementation of [`strcat` here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming/C_Reference/string.h/strcat).

Comment: Excuse me for using wrong terminology. By the term "header", I did not mean a header file; I meant the `char *StrAdd (char *dst, const char *src)` part at the top of the function.

Comment: @merkez3110 ,FYI, that is called a function definition

Comment: @remyabel : I've looked at the link you gave for the `strcat` implementation. Just another question: By directly adding `s2` to the tail of `s1`, as shown in the link, is there a risk to mess up the data (bytes) just residing next to `s1`?

Comment: @merkez3110 Yes you still need the space, it just replaces `memcpy`. I've put `strcat` example in my second case.